# Highlight multiple selected child nodes in a treeview

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I'm trying to select multiple child items in a treeview. All the child nodes are binded with a collection of a custom class objects i.e View.cs. Please note, treeview doesn't have treeview-items but a custom class to whom it is linked with.

The following code I've used to perform multiple node selections, it works perfectly fine (I checked it by debugging it). But it doesn't highlight the multiple selected child nodes on the UI. **I need a visual feedback so, a user would know which many nodes he has selected**. I'm not sure how to fix it, would appreciate any help.

```
    List<View> selectedViewItems = new List<View>();

    private static readonly PropertyInfo IsSelectionChangeActiveProperty = typeof(TreeView).GetProperty(
        "IsSelectionChangeActive",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
    );

    public static void AllowMultiSelection(TreeView treeView)
    {
        if (IsSelectionChangeActiveProperty == null) return;

        SelectMultipleItemsOnTreeView(treeView, SheetManagerUserControl.Instance.selectedViewItems);
    }

    private static void SelectMultipleItemsOnTreeView(TreeView treeView, List<View> selectedItems)
    {
        treeView.SelectedItemChanged += (a, b) =>
        {
            var treeViewItem = treeView.SelectedItem as View;

            if (treeViewItem == null) return;

            // allow multiple selection 
            // when key key is pressed 
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
            {
                // delete selection change notification 
                // select all items 
                // restore change notifications 
                var isSelectionChangeActive = IsSelectionChangeActiveProperty.GetValue(treeView, null);

                IsSelectionChangeActiveProperty.SetValue(treeView, true, null);
                selectedItems.ForEach(item => item.IsSelected = true);

                IsSelectionChangeActiveProperty.SetValue
                (
                    treeView,
                    isSelectionChangeActive,
                    null
                );
            }
            else
            {
                // deselect all selected items except the current one 
                selectedItems.ForEach(item => item.IsSelected = (item == treeViewItem));
                selectedItems.Clear();
            }

            if (!selectedItems.Contains(treeViewItem))
            {
                selectedItems.Add(treeViewItem);
            }
            else
            {
                // deselect if already selected 
                treeViewItem.IsSelected = false;
                selectedItems.Remove(treeViewItem);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: You could write an ItemTemplate that displays the selection highlighting.

Comment: I don't know how helpful this is, but I have project with multiple-selection in a TreeView, using an attached behavior, based on the [example on this page](http://www.codecadwallader.com/2015/11/22/wpf-treeview-with-multi-select/) which is itself based on the [example on this page](http://chrigas.blogspot.de/2014/08/wpf-treeview-with-multiple-selection.html).